# Help me answer this Number Theory question on GCD (involves exponents)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Basically I need a good hint how to solve the problem.I have solved it partly.

> $gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=2^{gcd(a,b)}-1$.

I have reached till:

> $gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=gcd(2^{a-b}-1,2^b-1)$

How to proceed from here.

*Please give detailed answer if you are using special manipulation or property please do explain how do you use it in this problem to solve it*.

Thanks.

Comment: You can now continue, replicating the Euclidean algorithm on the exponents.

Comment: @user1537366 I just need a hint not the whole solution.It is little bit different.The way I am trying to solve is different.

Comment: Alright, that was given by mixedmath.

Answer (score 1):

Using your lemma, you have the seeds of a variant of Euclid's algorithm.

In particular, wlog, $a>b$ and so $a = db + r$ for some positive $d$ and $0 < r \leq b.$ Therefore, using your lemma $d$ times, shows that $gcd(2^a−1,2^b−1) = gcd(2^b−1, 2^r−1)$ and $gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, r)$ (with this last following from Euclid's algorithm, more or less).

Now, there are two cases, either, r = b, and the RHS is $2^b−1 = 2^{gcd(a, b)} -1$ and we're done, or you need to reduce again, as in Euclid's algorithm. Either way, you eventually find yourself in the first case (after at most b reductions), and then, following the chain of implications back, you'll have your result.

Answer (score 0):

First consider the case when $(a,b)=1$. By Bezout theorem, there exists $u,v>0$ such that $au-bv=1$. Let $\gcd (2^a-1,2^b-1)=t$, then $t|2^{au}-1$, or $2^{bv+1}\equiv 1\pmod t$, or $2\equiv 1 \pmod t$, then $t=1$.

If $\gcd(a,b)=d>1$, then $\gcd \left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\right)=1$ and just apply the above case.

**Hint to continue your solution:**
Just consider Euclide's way to compute the GCD.

Answer (score 0):

We outline a somewhat clumsy induction proof.

Suppose the result holds for all pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\le k$, $b\le k$. We show the result holds for all $(a,b)$ with $a\le k+1$, $b\le k+1$.

So let $a\le k+1$, $b\le k+1$. If $a\le k$ and $b\le k$, we know the result holds. If $a=k+1$ and $b=k+1$, the result is easy to verify. So we can assume that $a=k+1$ and $b\le k$.

By your result, $\gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=\gcd(2^{a-b}-1, 2^b-1)$. By the induction assumption, this is $2^{\gcd(a-b,b)}-1$. But $\gcd(a-b,b)=\gcd(a,b)$ so we are finished.

A much nicer conceptual proof is to observe that the process of subtracting the smaller number from the bigger that you initiated is precisely the (original) Euclidean gcd algorithm, so after a number of iterations of your procedure our two numbers are each $2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$. But that takes a fair bit of notation to write up formally.